# socket simple question python

Tags: python, sockets

i am building a voice messenger type application ... my server application is expected to receive several connections and should b given the option to choose one connection...

my problem is i do not know how to display the ip adress of all the connections that are coming before i pick one specific ip and connect to it .. 
i am using python on ubuntu ...

Comment: I'm curious why your server doesn't just accept all incoming connections?

Comment: it does accept...i want it to accept only the one i choose based on the incoming IP ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API mechanism that allows you to read the peer address of a *potential* connection *before* you `accept(2)` that connection. It doesn't exist at the sockets level, so it's not going to be in Python, either.

If you want to build *way* too much knowledge of your operating environment into your application, you can always use `libpcap` or `winpcap` or similar tools to sniff the wire for incoming traffic, but (a) this requires elevated privileges, which is often a horrible idea (b) is really unrelated to most communication server tasks.

What the `tcp_wrappers` mechanism does is `accept(2)` the incoming connection, call `getpeername(2)` on the socket, and then `close(2)` the socket if the program using the `tcp_wrappers` shouldn't be talking with that remote peer. (See `/etc/hosts.allow`, `/etc/hosts.deny`, and `/etc/hosts.options`, `hosts.allow(5)` manpage.) This might be rude to the clients, but the sysadmin decided to forbid talking with them anyway, so being friendly isn't a very high priority.

So, is it acceptable to simply `close(2)` connections *after* you have already `accept(2)`ed the connection? If so, you can use [`socket.getpeername()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getpeername) to find the IP of the remote peer, do what you need, and then call [`socket.close()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) on the socket if you shouldn't have accepted the connection in the first place.

Comment: yeah that should do the job for me...rest a'll implement some control logic..thanks ...